# how to protect my pages with protected routes in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm fairly new in reactjs and I'm having trouble creating protected routes in reactjs. Basically I want just one page to be behind authorized route. I looked at tyler mcginnis guide but I didn't quite understand it all, maybe because that authorization is done in one page only while I have app.js, login.js, and dashboard.js page so I'm having a hard time trying to connect the dots from that guide into my project. If anyone could please help me with this, I would highly appreciate it. I just want my dashboard page behind login.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./login";
import Dashboard from "./dashboard";
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navheader">
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/Login"} className="nav-link">
                    Login
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <br />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

login.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App";
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
    this.onchange = this.onchange.bind(this);
  }
  onchange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  performLogin = async () => {
    var body = {
      password: this.state.password,
      email: this.state.email
    };
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const url = "/api/authenticate";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const text = await response.text();
      console.log(response.token);
      if (text === "redirect") {
        this.props.history.push(`/dashboard`);
      } else if (text === "verifyemail") {
        this.props.history.push(`/verifyOtp/${this.state.email}`);
      } else {
        console.log("login failed");
        window.alert("login failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="loginForm">
          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <TextField
              hintText="Enter your Email"
              floatingLabelText="Email"
              onChange={(event, newValue) => this.setState({ email: newValue })}
            />
            <br />
            <TextField
              type="password"
              hintText="Enter your password"
              floatingLabelText="password"
              onChange={(event, newValue) =>
                this.setState({ password: newValue })
              }
            />
            <br />
            <RaisedButton
              label="Submit"
              primary={true}
              style={style}
              onClick={event => this.performLogin(event)}
            />
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
const style = {
  margin: 15
};
export default Login;
```

dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  logout = () => {
     //not sure what to do here
  };
  render() {


    return (
      <>
        <div>hello</div>
        <button onCLick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(Dashboard);
```

I'm not sure where to add these things. Like if I add them in login.js then how do I change the props cause isAuthenticated would be coming from App.js I think because states are needed to be declared in the higher most component or am I misunderstanding something?

```
const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true
    setTimeout(cb, 100)
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false
    setTimeout(cb, 100)
  }
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
  )} />
)
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-shirley-nn235)